# android user interface error

Tags: android

I am following this tutorial and at the end of it i have the following code, but when i run app i do not get a button or a text field, just  hello world.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

What is the problem

layout xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:orientation="horizontal" 



     tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
     android:aalyout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="text"="@string/buton_send"/>
```

String values

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <resources>

         <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
        <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
        <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
        <string name="button_send">Send</string>
```

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: first layout should be in res/layout/ not AndroidManifest ... next in Activity onCreate method you should use setContentView(R.layout.xxxx) to set layout for you Activity(where xxx is your new layout xml file from /res/layout/)

Comment: the first block of code is from the activity_main.xml not manifest

Comment: no, i dont not get an error it just shows the emulator with My first app and hello world as content.

Comment: try to clear the project ... maybe eclipse build it with old activity_main.xml ...

Comment: now it says [2013-04-11 11:05:16 - MyFirstApp] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Comment: There's no end tag for LinearLayout element

Comment: there an end tag, i missed it when copying it

Comment: the error is on this line          android:text="text"="@string/buton_send"// it says multiple annotations found at this line

Comment: still  the same error after changing the android:text="text"="@string/buton_send"/> to android:text="@string/buton_send"/>

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:text="text"="@string/buton_send"/>` to `android:text="@string/buton_send"/>`

Comment: Add an id to the last button :D

Answer (score 0):

our layout should go as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button1"   //here you missed the id....in your code
 android:aalyout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/buton_send"/>   //your code has incorrect syntax here
```